# DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Query was empty

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

First post. Please bear with me if formatting isn't one-hundred per-cent. Thanks.

I'm in the process of migrating from an older centos server to one with a more up-to-date Debian 9 operating system and I've run into several program incompatibilities... but it hasn't been all bad. I have the full LAMP stack working and "several databases and their pages" up and running just fine. Unfortunately, I've run into a snag. I'll walk through it...

In my www-accessible perl script, I don't include login details in a publically accessible location. I initiate MySQL like so...

```perl
use DBI ;
require "connect.cgi" ;
&my_connect();
```

In the connection file, I have like this...

```perl
sub my_connect {
  $dsn = "DBI:mysql:dbmydatabase:localhost" ;
  $user_name = 'uMyUser';
  $user_pass = 'pMyPassword';
  $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user_name, $user_pass, { RaiseError => 1} ) ;
  return $dbh;
}
```

So far, so good. I've checked the connection like so...

```perl
if(!$dbh){
  die "failed to connect to MySQL database DBI->errstr()";
}else{
  print("Connected to MySQL server successfully.\n");
}
```

... and all appears fine and dandy.

I also call for execution from the connection file, like so...

```sql
sub Do_SQL {
  $sth = $dbh->prepare($SQL);
  $rv = $sth->execute;
  return $sth;
}
```

And for the task -- I want to check for the existence of a record in a database. So I set it up and run it...

```sql
$SQL = qq/ SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM `table1` WHERE `col1` = '$col1') /;

&Do_SQL;
```

Trouble is, I'm getting an empty query message.

```sql
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Query was empty at connect.cgi line 54.
```

I have tried a few variations on the query. For example...

```sql
$SQL = qq/ SELECT count(*) FROM `table1` WHERE `col1` = '$col1') /;
$SQL = qq/ SELECT `id` FROM `table1` WHERE `col1` = '$col1') /;
$SQL = qq/ SELECT * FROM `table1`  /;
```

... but the result is the same.

I might be tempted to suggest there is some sort of version incompatibility between old and new set up but I have several other pages with similar configuration working fine. A difference might be that the stuff I have working was backed up and restored from previous databases. Whereas this current problem is the first new database I've created from scratch on the new server.

Interestingly, the queries I note above work on the command line. They do not work within the perl script. I've done several searches but can find nothing to point toward a solution. So here I am seeking the benefit and wisdom of more experience than my own.

Thanks for your insights.

Comment: Passing arguments to your functions (And using the returned values) is going to be more reliable and less error-prone than relying on global variables... And of course if you're not already doing so, make sure to `use strict; use warnings;` to help discover potential issues earlier.

Comment: You should also be binding values to parameters in your query instead of directly including variables like `$col1` in a query string, to help with sql injection issues.

Comment: @Shawn. Yes, I am passing arguments and using strict. My example attempts to cut to the problem rather than ask you, or anybody, to read reams of irrelevant code. That said, I'm not sure what you mean by "binding values to parameters". However, I can assure you I do a lot of error checking and input validation.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't do any of that; it's hard to debug when we can't even see what you're really doing. And just search for 'sql injection' and read the DBI documentation to learn how to use parameters in sql queries.

Comment: From the code you posted, it seems most likely that sub Do_SQL is in the scope of a different $SQL variable than the one you are setting.  You should be passing that to the sub.  And of that's what you are doing, you need to show us that code.

Comment: @Shawn. Actually, you did remarkably well. After responding to you a few moments ago, I went back to re-trace program flow and discovered that while I had used strict and declared variables locally I had also relied on the same variable name in the script and in my authentication/connect file. This is posted above. But because of the same name I had taken it for granted the same value was being used in the function, when in fact it was not. Once I discovered this, I changed up the name which forced a new declaration. With that done, the empty query hurdle was overcome.

Comment: We posted at very nearly the same time, but yes you pegged it. Proof once again we should never stray from discipline and good coding practice. I still have a few wrinkles to work out but nothing catastrophic. So, a well done to you and grateful appreciation from me.

Comment: Again, well spotted!

And to round this out. A quick search and I found a decent page on sql injection on w3schools. Yes, I've seen that sort of thing in action and I try to be on my toes with it. As for DBI, I have O'Reilly's Programming the Perl DBI. It probably wouldn't hurt to browse it again for a refresher.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't call subroutines as `&name_of_sub` This passes the existing contents of `@_` into the subroutine. It's best practice to not use `&` at all when calling a subroutine.

Comment: @JGNI, pedantically, `&my_connect` would pass `@_` into the subroutine, `&my_connect()` doesn't. But, yes, calling a subroutine using `&` is never necessary and is usually an indication of someone copying old code without understanding it.

Comment: @Dave Cross & JGNI, thanks to you both for pointing up things I was unaware of. Dave, copying code? - no. Everything I've done has been from scratch and I've tried to learn as I go. But I make no claim to expertise and it's been a long while since I've done any of this. Mistakes are bound to find their way in, through inexperience and through trial and especially error. But tightening up the strictures is a personal goal. Missing the scope was careless and this post was a nice wake up call. So, thanks again.

Comment: @Bobby: Sorry, yes, it's not always copying old code. Sometimes it's caused by learning from old web sites or books. And, actually, I think it's still (disappointingly) in *Learning Perl*. You might find [this blog post](https://perlhacks.com/2015/04/subroutines-and-ampersands/) interesting.